# SQL Select to Merge Key Field When Row is a Duplicate

Tags: sql, select, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have my database as below:

```
ID | First | Surname | DOB
-----------------------------
01 | Homer | Simpson | 12-May
02 | Homer | Simpson | 12-May
03 | Marge | Bouvier | 19-Mar
```

I am looking to run a SQL `select` query on the database, to create results where a new unique ID is created by merging the unique fields of the duplicated rows?

```
ID      | First | Surname | DOB
----------------------------------
01 / 02 | Homer | Simpson | 12-May
03      | Marge | Bouvier | 19-Mar
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Sorry @GordonLinoff added now.  Oracle database.

Comment: might be duplicate -> https://stackoverflow.com/q/273238/11878472

Comment: @Tejas that is `sql-server` where mine is `oracle-sql`, otherwise yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are asking for some sort of string aggregation function.  This depends on the database, but the idea is:

```
select listagg(id, ' / ') within group (order by id) as ids,
       first, surname, dob
from t
group by first, surname, dob;
```

The name of the `listagg()` function -- and exact syntax -- vary by database.

Comment: Well that worked very nicely, and very elegant solution.  I've never heard of `listagg` before.  Every day is a school day!